# Which mortise lock/brand I should get to replace this one?

Tags: doors, lock

I got the Marks Metro mortise from HomeDepot and thought it would match the current size (I thought mortise has a standard size). However, when I try to replace it, the old mortise is a bit bigger. 
I can't find any brand information on the old one. Any idea which size/brand will match this mortise? The bigger one is the one that I want to match.

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can you put it in and fit it (other holes line up)? if so then just putting in some shims would work.

Comment: +1 for shim-to-fit if possible. The alternative is to get accurate measurements of the mortise, then see if anyone still makes a lock which nicely fits that space. Or fill in and then re-mortise the door. Or replace the door.

Comment: no... can't fit in because the top and bottom screw holes are not align.... the old one is also having a longer faceplate so the screw holes position are not the same position

Comment: Question: Why are you replacing the old one?

Comment: mainly because the lock looks old and dirty... and there were like 20 who had the key before...

Comment: Refinished and Rekey seems to be a more reasonable solution in this case. You would be surprised what some naval jelly and metal furniture polish would do as far as improving the look. Having it re-keyed is also a non-issue for most locksmiths. *Comment because it's not the requested answer*

Comment: The solution to too many keys is to rekey or replace the lock cylinder(s), which doesn't require replacing the mortise mechanism. A bit of cleaning/polishing will solve the pretty problem,  though frankly nobody looks at the door edge... Actually, I would have expected a cover plate over the face of the lock, both for pretty and to discourage tampering with the cylinder setscrews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the right (the old one) is an old Russwin Emhart mortise lock. You can still purchase ones like it from Corbin Russwin but they are quite pricey. If you want to replace the Emhart with the Marks Metro, a few shims and a new strike plate as well as some alterations to the door/door jamb should do the trick.

Comment: I'd almost say that if it *is* an Emhart -- having a good locksmith put a current Emhart cylinder in it (if possible) might get you something better than the Marks Metro...

Answer (score 0):

You can add some shims in the mortise and plug the existing screw holes so you can reposition them. If the plate does not fit then enlarging the hole for it with a chisel will work.

There are 2 things that you will want to align:

1. the holes in the door jamb where the lock engages (a.k.a. the strike plate). to help with that add some masking tape with markings on the door to compare the new vs. the old.
2. the holes in the door for the knob and locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth , I dealt with something similar recently. Unfortunately the building owner had already purchased the expensive lock, so trying to match the old ones was not an option. Solution was to replace the strike with one that matched the new lock's bolts. We were lucky and found an electric strike that could do the job without requiring much alteration to the door frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one on the right is a Schlage commercial lock.  There are many suppliers besides Schlage that make them, but the key word is "commercial".